# PHP_SELF call for the same file

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";

}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

i want only if part to run after submit and display form should not be seen after clicking submit form button

Comment: put that form in else part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your html form code inside else part.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";

} else {
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    echo "User has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";

    exit;
}
```